# Finding composition of relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've provided an example and my answer, however I am worried I have done $R\circ S$, or $S\circ R$, as I still mix them up at times.

ex: Suppose $R$ and $S$ are relations on $\{a, b, c, d\}$ where $R = \{(a, b), (a, d), (b, c), (c, c), (d, a)\}$ and $S = \{(a, c), (b, d), (d, a)\}$

my answer: $R\circ S = \{(d, c), (a, d), (a, a)\}$

I feel like I mixed it up again and found $S \circ R$, is there a trick to not mix it up, or do you just have to learn from your mistakes?

Comment: $(R\circ S)(a) = R(S(a)) = R(c) = c$